# Removing whitespace from header

Tags: header, border, space

I wrap around my header and paragraph with a `<div>`. I gave it an ID called help. In css, I style the element to give it a border and a background to the header tag. How do remove the white space above the header inside the border? I only know how to use margins and paddings.

**HTML:**

```
    <div id="help">
    <h2>Help</h2>
    <p>Here are some text for place holder. This will be some random text. Blah blah. No grammar no nothing. How does this work. haha No idea.Here are some text for place holder. This will be some random text. Blah blah. No grammar no nothing. How does this work. haha No idea.Here are some text for place holder. This will be some random text. Blah blah. No grammar no nothing. How does this work. haha No idea.</p>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#help {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 20%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the default margin on the `<h2>` element, you also need to target the div properly with #help:    
**HTML:**

```
    <div id="help">
    <h2>Help</h2>
    <p>Here are some text for place holder. This will be some random text. Blah blah. No grammar no nothing. How does this work. haha No idea.Here are some text for place holder. This will be some random text. Blah blah. No grammar no nothing. How does this work. haha No idea.Here are some text for place holder. This will be some random text. Blah blah. No grammar no nothing. How does this work. haha No idea.</p>  
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #help {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: white;
    width: 20%;
    }

    h2{
    margin-top: 0px;
    }
```